# random number generator on the basis of integer or float

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

I have an 2D array

```
b=[[1,100],[0.0,0.8],[11,111],[0.8,0.999],[11,111],[16,256],[1,10]]
```

which contain both integer and floating point numbers. I want to select a random number. I am going through loop:

```
for i in range(6):
   aa=b[i][0]
   bb=b[i][1]
   a[i]=rand(aa,bb)
   print(a[i])
```

Now I want to select random number from range in "variable" and when its integer, it select a random from integer number and whens its float it select random float number from range in "b".

I have seen functions, either they return float or integer random number but not both.

Answer (score 1):

This will generate a list of random numbers that are integers or floats according to the contents of the ranges in `b`:

```
[(random.randrange if isinstance(lower, int) 
  else random.uniform)(lower, upper) 
 for lower, upper in b]
```

Here we simply choose to use [`random.randrange`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randrange) if we encounter an integer, otherwise we use [`random.uniform`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.uniform)

Comment: Can you explain this more, i didn't get it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Build a custom method which accepts the range parameter.
2. If the range is integer, just generate random number in the range.
3. If the range is float, convert the range into integer i.e. [0.8,0.999] becomes 800,999 with factor multiplication of 10^3 ( or you can use 10^4 for higher precision). Generate a random integer between 800-999, say 856, divide it be multiplication factor used for float --> integer conversion, which would be 10^3 in this case, so your random float is 0.856.
4. The decision of how big multiplication factor to use would lie in what level of decimal precision your float range is.